# Why do drupal-media elements not get rendered in Layout Builder CKEditor?

Tags: media, layout-builder

1. In Layout Builder, add a custom block.
2. When editing the block in CKEditor, add an image using "Insert from Media Library" button.
3. Exit CKEditor.
4. Re-edit the block in CKEditor.

Result: I do not see the image (rendered `drupal-media` element). If I reload the page and edit, I see the rendered image. The image appears the first time I edit in CKEditor but not on subsequent times during the same page load.

I do not see any log messages or messages in the browser console. When it fails, the `drupal-media` element is present when I view source. It just doesn't get rendered.

I cannot reproduce this on a stock Drupal site. Any suggestions of what to look for to debug? What is supposed to render the element? It appears that this is just not running.